# unable to connect to google cloud instance

Tags: linux, bash, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I was unable to ssh my current instance so I created a snapshot of the disk in current instance.

Then, used that snapshot to create an new instance.

also, I changed the ssh login to os login for that project.

Now, after restarting both the servers, both the servers give connection timed out error.

attached Instance startup log [here](https://gist.github.com/dinso/cbd1122743abb7c558bf76f50e2e03dd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation [Handling the "Could not connect, retrying..." error](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#couldnotconnecterror):

> The boot disk of the instance has run out of free space. When the
>   connection is established, the guest environment updates the
>   ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file with the public SSH key used for the
>   current session. If the disk runs out of free space, the update fails.
>   To identify issues with disk space, **check the serial console output of
>   the instance and look for "No space left" errors**.

and as I can see in the log file:

```
...
Feb 12 17:07:13 amdigit-staging cloud-init[646]: tee: /var/log/cloud-init-output.log: No space left on device
...
Feb 12 17:07:13 amdigit-staging cloud-init[646]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
...
```

To solve this issue:

> - [Resize](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd) the boot persistent disk of the instance to increase its size.    If the operating system image used by the instance [supports
>     automatic    resizing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_partitions), this is the easiest option because the
>     operating system    automatically resizes the root partition to match
>     the new size after    the instance is restarted.
> - If you know which files are using the disk space, [create a startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) that deletes the unnecessary files and frees space for the
>     instance to start. Restart the instance so that the script executes
>     and cleans the files. Be careful to use the correct command and
>     delete the correct files. After your instance starts and you are able 
>     to connect to the instance through SSH, set the startup-script
>     metadata item back so it does not continue to delete the files.
> - For information about how to access the instance's disk, see [General tips for using Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting).

If you still have a problem, you should follow Recovering an inaccessible instance or a full boot disk guide:

> **If an instance is completely out of disk space** or if it is not running
>   a Linux guest environment, **then automatically resizing your root
>   filesystem isn't possible**, even after you've increased the size of the
>   persistent disk that backs it. If you can't connect to your instance,
>   or your boot disk is full and you can't resize it, **you must create a
>   new instance and recreate the boot disk from a snapshot to resize it**.

step by step instructions you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#inaccessible_instance).

Comment: very much thanks for giving detail on what is happening. It really helped to find a solution to the problem.